# problem with eclipse build cmake espidf Error: could not find CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME in Cache

Tags: c++, eclipse, cmake, esp32, esp-idf

I have a problem with the eclipse IDE with ESP-IDF, every time that i build a project i get this massage-

```
Building in: C:\Users\eclipse-workspace06\blynk\build
Configuring in: C:\Users\eclipse-workspace06\blynk\build
cmake -G Ninja -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=D:\espidfeclipse\esp-idf-v5.0\tools\cmake\toolchain-esp32.cmake -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON -DCCACHE_ENABLE=1 -DIDF_TARGET=esp32 C:\Users\eclipse-workspace06\blynk
-- Found Git: C:/Program Files/Git/cmd/git.exe (found version "2.28.0.windows.1") 
CMake Error at D:/espidfeclipse/esp-idf-v5.0/tools/cmake/build.cmake:181 (file):
  file FILE([TO_CMAKE_PATH|TO_NATIVE_PATH] path result) must be called with
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  exactly three arguments.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  D:/espidfeclipse/esp-idf-v5.0/tools/cmake/idf.cmake:53 (__build_init)
  D:/espidfeclipse/esp-idf-v5.0/tools/cmake/project.cmake:12 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:5 (include)


CMake Error at D:/espidfeclipse/esp-idf-v5.0/tools/cmake/project.cmake:18 (message):
  Internal error, PYTHON build property not set correctly.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:5 (include)


cmake --build . -- -v
Error: could not find CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME in Cache
Build complete (1 errors, 0 warnings): C:\Users\eclipse-workspace06\blynk\build
Total time taken to build the project: 246 ms
```

The code is an example code that works on VScode and Arduino, i installed and reinstalled every thing 100 times already. ( and if i build regular c++ it works alright)

I will be grateful for any help i can get.

Comment: My guess would be that you're missing a call to `project`, please show a [mre]

Comment: `file FILE([TO_CMAKE_PATH|TO_NATIVE_PATH] path result) ` probably one of the variables are  blank. Look at line 181 of `D:/espidfeclipse/esp-idf-v5.0/tools/cmake/build.cmake` and investigate the value of the parameters. You can edit the file and use message( STATUS MYVariableName="${MYVariableName}") and see if any are empty.

Comment: The [erroneous line](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/blob/v5.0/tools/cmake/build.cmake#L181) is `file(TO_CMAKE_PATH ${PYTHON} PYTHON)`. The variable `PYTHON` is set in the previous line with `set_default(PYTHON "python")`. The function [set_default](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/blob/v5.0/tools/cmake/utilities.cmake#L10) sets value of the CMake variable either to the value of environment variable with the same name, or to the given value. It seems you have `PYTHON` environment variable being set to the incorrect value (e.g., a space).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @drescherjm and @Tsyvarev for putting me on the right path.
I solved the problem and the solution is very odd. what i did was to delete all the python instances from the different environment variables and it worked for some bizarre reason.